# How does Finder decide if a file should be hidden?

Tags: macos, finder

There are quite a few files/direcotries under `/`. But Finder only shows 'System', 'Library', 'Users' and 'Applications'.

I create a directory called `/mnt`, and Finder shows it. Why? What is the difference between `/mnt` and other directories like `/bin` or `/usr` that makes it shown in Finder? Or how can I make `/mnt` hidden and make `/bin` shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer! It is controlled by the `hidden` flag. Open Terminal,

```
$ /bin/ls -Ol
```

will show you which files are flagged with `hidden`.

To make `/mnt` hidden, simply

```
$ sudo chflags hidden /mnt
```

To change back

```
$ sudo chflags nohidden /mnt
```

Cheers!