# why cannot I see Library folder under my home directory in Finder?

Tags: macbook-pro

I could see ~/Library through Unix command in Mac, yet I cannot see it in a Finder window. I need to go as Finder -> Go to folder -> ~/Library, then I can find it. Does anyone know why is it like that? Thanks! It's macOS Big Sur.

Comment: We have a number of previous questions about this: ["Where did the ~/Library folder go in Lion?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17797), ["How does Finder decide if a file should be hidden?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195823), and [this tip for opening it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18677/know-of-any-features-or-tips-and-tricks-in-os-x-10-7-lion/18704#18704). Also, [here's a MacWorld article about opening it](https://www.macworld.com/article/213360/view-library-folder-in-lion.html). Or is your question about *why* Apple decided to hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to always see your Library folder in the Finder, you select your Home Folder, then select "View" menu, then "Show View Options" (<kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), then check "Show Library Folder". The Library folder will be then visible in the Finder.

Comment: **NOTE:** This only works if one selects their **Home** _folder_ from the **Sidebar** in **Finder**. Selecting ones **Home** _folder_ anywhere else in **Finder** does not produce the necessary _view options_ containing the **[] Show Library Folder** _checkbox_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that folder is *hidden* by default along with another bunch of files and folders becasue *most* users never need or want to go into it.

To make it visible press:

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>

That's Shift-Command-Period, it will reveal all the hidden files. There is also a command to un-hide just the ~/Library folder:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```